# Applescript (or Excel Formula if possible) To Return a List of Values Based on a Value in Another Cell

Tags: excel, applescript

I have an excel spreadsheet with list of numbers in column A (ex. 3105, 3106, 3107, etc.). In column H I have a list of classes (ex. TD, PIGD, Intermediate). Some cells in column H only have 1 class others have 2 or even all 3 classes in the same cell. I want to return the number value in column A of the same row based on criteria from column H. Then I want all the values to be listed in numerical order in a list separated by commas.

Example

Column A: A1: 3105 A2: 3106 A3: 3107
Column H H1: TD H2: TD & PIGD H3: PIGD & Intermediate

Given the criteria the range of cells in column H only contains TD then the result would need to spit out 3105. But given the criteria that the range of cells in column H contains TD (no matter what else is in the cell also) then the result would need to spit out 3105, 3106.

I don't think this is possible with an excel formula or combination of arrays but if so please explain how. I'm sure it's possible with applescript but I just can't get it to work out.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a quick answer (and I hope I'm understanding your needs corrcetly), you can accomplish everything you asked for VERY easily by just using the `Filter` functionality in Excel.

If you filter that range, then:

- If you want just `TD`, then you just select `TD` in the filter drop-down list
- If you want anything that contains `TD`, then you select `Text Filters` > `Contains..` > `TD`

I hope this makes sense and, if this is not what you're looking for, then please explain further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thats part of it. I want to filter like you described but I don't want to return the values I filter. I want to return the value in Column A that corresponds to the row that the filtered cell lies in in Column H. i.e. if 20 different cells are filtered at random from Column H then I want a list of the 20 different values from Column A. I'm not sure if I could return all the values to the same cell or if would have to return the values to different cells first then oriente them horizontally and then save them as a CSV file to get them in the output format I need.

Comment: Where that list is shown at I really don't care I just need it in a format that is easily converted to something like this "3105, 3106, 3107" etc. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, if you make a table spanning from Column A to Column H, you can then get the values you want in Column A. What you can do next is just copy that (filtered) list in Col A to a new worksheet and then, the easiest way I accomlish making a separated list is, suppose you paste that list into Column A of the new sheet, in B1, you'd put in the formula `=A1`, in B2, you'd put in the formula `=B1 & ", " & A2`, then drag B2 all the way down. The value in the last row of Column B will be your entire list. Hope that makes sense.